# Show the credit/debit card page directly on paypal

Tags: wordpress, paypal, woocommerce

I'm working on an e-commerce site which runs on WordPress platform. Woocommerce plugin is used to create the products and using PayPal standard payment gateway.

Whenever I check out the product, the PayPal is showing the "Paypal login page" but I wanted to show "Pay with credit/debit" by default.

I tried setting this '' to the checkout button in my site. I doesn't work.

I know "Express checkout" is used to show the "Paypal credit/debit" card page directly. But in my products, I have maintained the recurring payment option. "Express Checkout" doesn't provide the recurring payment option.

May I know where I'm going wrong.

Note: I'm using latest versions of woocommerce and wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

I believe since you are using PayPal standard, you may need to utilize another form of integrating recurring payments for your respective products. Looks like PayPal does endorse a specific extension to WooCommerce that can handle recurring payments, link **[HERE](https://www.paypal.com/us/smarthelp/article/how-do-i-integrate-paypal-payments-standard-subscriptions-with-woocommerce-subscriptions-ts2098)**.

Also, here's the actual link to the extension which is mentioned on the previous page, [**HERE**](https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-subscriptions/).

Comment: Hi @Calico. Thanks for the reply. The problem is not with the subscription. I have properly configured those things. I need to show the "Credit/Debit card page" by default on paypal payment page.

Answer (score 0):

According to [REST API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#definition-order_application_context) documentation, on v2/checkout/orders you may set the application_context.landing_page to BILLING.

Unfortunately, I can't see any difference on user experience behaviour.